# Does this Sequence Converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the sequence $\{\frac{n!-3n}{n!+2n}\}$ from $n = 1$ to $n = \infty$ converge?  I want to eyeball the series and say yes because I'm assuming it converges infinity because there is an $n!$ in both the numerator and the denominator.  Is there a more formal way to do this problem?

Comment: Please edit your question: sequence should be series.

Comment: Could you please explain what you might mean by "I want to eyeball the series"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!-3n}{n!+2n}=1,
$$
the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!-3n}{n!+2n}$$ cannot converge.

Comment: Hmmm, so if the series diverges, then the sequence also diverges?  Conversely, if the series converges, the the sequence converges as well?

Comment: I think he wants sequence. the trick is to divide both numerator and denominator by $n!$ and you should see what happens in the limit!

Comment: and no the series can diverge even if the sequence converges, see harmonic sum for example